# Timestamp datetime64 to datetime in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, datetime64

I am confused with `datetime64` and trying convert it to a normal time format.

I have a column with timestamp format: `2022.01.02D23:10:12.197164900`.

Output expected is: `2022-01-02 23:10:12`

I'm trying with:

```
df['executionTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['executionTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Try changing the `format` argument to `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['executionTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['executionTime'], format='%Y.%m.%dD%H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: It won't result in the expected result I think. The expected output is something like `2022-01-02 23:10:12`

Comment: For me it produces `2022-01-02 23:10:12.197164900`, @Amirhossein.

Comment: It seems you were right about the OP's problem:) Although the OP mentioned that "Output expected is : 2022-01-02 23:10:12". Anyway, +1 for your fine answer:)

Comment: @richardec yeah will do :)

Comment: Yeah...it included the milli-/micro-seconds, but I assumed that the OP wouldn't mind those...

Comment: Yeah I don't need miliseconds, btw you guys know how I can actually + or - some minutes on this time format?

Comment: @Eigenvector Try using `timedelta` to add and subtract date objects.

Comment: Sure @Eigenvector: to add, e.g., 5 hours and 3 minutes, use `df['executionTime'] += pd.Timedelta(hours=5, minutes=3)`. Swap the `+=` to `-=` to subtract instead of add.

Comment: @richardec like I want to compare with other table where those timestamp is same format, I need to get the row where timestamp + or - 15 minutes. You can suggest me what is the best way to do?